# Add a 2 character prefix to the SKU on the product detail page

Tags: magento2, product-view, magento2.3.2, sku

I've been trying without success to prepend the the SKU on the product detail page with 2 characters - R9.

I've already added some customisations to the page using a catalog_product_view.xml but I can't seem to target the block product.info.sku

I think something like this in the theme catalog_product_view.xml should work:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="skuPrefix">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="skuPrefix" xsi:type="string">skuPrefix</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

but it doesn't. I can get the block to appear with this:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
        <container name="custom.container3" before="-">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="skuprefix" template="Magento_Catalog::skuprefix.phtml" />
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

but that doesn't put the block where I want it. We're using Luma and we're on 2.3.2. Ideally I'd like the SKU to look like this: SKU#: R912345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you will check `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`file then you will see magento use `Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml` template for sku so you can override this template to your theme and can add prefix from that file.

Add below line after `$_code = $block->getAtCode();`

```
$prefix = ($_code && $_code == 'sku') ? 'R9' : '';
```

and echo that $prefix variable before `<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeValue ?>` so it will look like :

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $prefix ?><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeValue ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Satish, this is a great solution. I'd hoped to figure our how to update the prefix from the admin panel but it only changes once a year so it's not a major issue.